# How to get the content of a json file from google cloud storage in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to read a JSON file from google cloud storage from my HTML
but he didn't work.
This is my json context:{'first_name': 'Anat'}
How can I get the context file?

This is my part of my html context:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.first_name;
 }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://storage.googleapis.com/{backetname}/{filename}.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: There’s another, more modern method "fetch", that somewhat deprecates XMLHttpRequest. Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Assuming that you correctly followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#rest-make-object-public) to make your object (JSON file) publicly accessible you could use the [`fetch` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) described by @WillBlack to read the JSON content.

Comment: Thanks for the response, now I saw that the reason I have a problem is: "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." can anyone help with that?do I need to change the configuration of the bucket?